# How to run a Java jar consecutively?

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, executable-jar

I have 5 java jars in server "A" and a dozen of jars in other server "B". Now I need to run them consecutively. Say if 1 jar in server A has run complete, then 2 jars related to the jar 1 should start to run in server B. How to achieve this?

One option we have considered is to club related jars in one aws server and run through script detecting the jar completion through the log files, but is there any other efficient way to achieve the synchronisation through spring framework or by any other means?

Comment: Look at message brokers like RabbitMQ. You can have all your jars running at the same time and subscribed to the message broker then as one completes it can send a message letting it know it it completed and the others can kick off then.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into having two "manager apps" on each server that can communicate with each other through sockets. Say manager app on server A detects jar 1 is completed, then it would send a message to manager app on server B with a command to run the jars related to the jar 1 on server A. To complete this I would look into Server Sockets and Sockets.